# Xcode ios build setting error

Tags: xcode, ios6

after refactoring and updating group names , I get this error on building ;

```
clang: error: no such file or directory:   
'/Users/yves/github/MOBILE/work/StoryboardAnalyses/StoryboardRecipes/StoryboardAnalyses-      Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

in fact StoryboardRecipes directory has been changed to StoryboardAnalyses,

is there anyway to modify it in the settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Xcode, in the left hand area with the files and groups, down at the bottom there's a row of small buttons.  Click the one that looks like a little box with another box inside (tool tip is "Show only files with source control status") and look for red files in the file browser.  These are file references pointing to places where no file currently exists.  You'll probably have one for everything in StoryboardRecipes.

If you have a group called StoryboardRecipes you might be able to fix everything under the group by changing the group's name to StoryboardAnalysis.  If all else fails you can blow away the whole group and re-add it.  This is all manageable in Xcode's file browser.  You shouldn't have to modify any build settings for missing file issues.

Answer (score 0):

Go into your build settings and perform a search for the old name which will be the place that you need to change it..